# javascript: check if mouse is down(pressed) and start counting from zero, after x seconds, it redirect

Tags: javascript, mousedown

is it possible to detect our mouse when down(pressed), and start counting from zero for a few seconds...and after 5 seconds mousedown, it redirect.

I have found a script that does it, but I am confuse on how to show the second when the mouse is being pressed.

Here it is.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
document.getElementsByClassName=function(classname){
  var pattern=new RegExp("(^|\s)"+classname+"(\s|$)");
  var results=new Array();
  var d=document.getElementsByTagName('*'), l=d.length;
  for (var k=0; k<l; k++) if (pattern.test(d[k].className)) results.push(d[k]);
  return results;
}

var timer;

function startStuff(el,ii)
{
  var temp=el.innerHTML;
  timer=window.setTimeout('doStuff("'+temp+'");',3000);
}

function stopStuff(el)
{
  window.clearTimeout(timer);
}

function doStuff(l)
{
<?php echo"<html>"; header( 'Location: http://www.google.com' ) ; echo"</html>";?>
}

window.onload=function() {
  var links=document.getElementsByClassName('clicker');
  for (var i=0; i<links.length; i++)
  {
    links[i].onmousedown=function() {startStuff(this)};
    links[i].onmouseup  =function() {stopStuff(this)};
  }
}

/*]]>*/
</script> 

</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="clicker">Link1</a>
<a href="#">Link2</a>
<a href="#" class="clicker">Link3</a>
</body>
</html>
```

If possible, I want the second is displayed with images....

Comment: Why would you want to use images to show the seconds, when the browser could more easily show the countdown in seconds? And what images do you want to show?

Comment: well, I just think of an image.. images that is saved by each number, 1, 2, etc...  and then, after I rethink about it, more simple with just generated text in seconds. spare my complex mind of thinking.. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use images. Try something like this:

```
link = document.getElementById('redirect');
counter = document.getElementById('counter');
timeRemaining = 5000;

link.onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  setInterval(function(){
    if (timeRemaining > 0) {
      timeRemaining -= 1000;
      counter.innerHTML = timeRemaining/1000;
    } else {
      window.location = link.href;
    }
  },1000);
};
```

Full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <title>Redirect to Google</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="http://www.google.com" id="redirect">
    Go to google in <span id="counter">5</span> seconds
  </a>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    link = document.getElementById('redirect');
    counter = document.getElementById('counter');
    timeRemaining = 5000;

    link.onclick = function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      setInterval(function(){
        if (timeRemaining > 0) {
          timeRemaining -= 1000;
          counter.innerHTML = timeRemaining/1000;
        } else {
          window.location = link.href;
        }
      },1000);
    };
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that this will degrade gracefully if javascript is disabled, because then you are left with a simple link.

Comment: okay, got it. because I'm still new here, then I will wait for my reputation reach 15, then I will upvote your answer.. :)